Is there a plugin in chartjs that show a paired result i.e. high and low on the same axes?
I'm trying to find if there is an existing plugin that can show below in chartjs
Blood Pressure Graph
It looks like this could be achievable in high charts
```
https://jsfiddle.net/ssdg6nug
```

This looks like a stacked bar graph but instead it's a line. And since this graph will be use in a clinical settings, the arrows are really a must
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked-groups.html
I've looked at the line stacked but it's not the same
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/area/line-stacked.html
Unfortunately, for this project, we're creating multiple charts and we have been using chartjs for all of the other charts. We would like to use chartjs for all for consistencies

I think this is what you need. I'm basically hiding the segment when the x-axis is different
``` https://jsfiddle.net/dt5zLgay ```



Wow! Thank you so much again sir.

no problem. I hope that helps.
